# SQLiteBlobTooBigException for query with small data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a strange problem when executing a query in SQLite-Database I created for cities and their locations:

> 2020-01-29 16:45:17.506 13110-13169/xxx.debug E/CursorWindow: Failed
>   to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 0
>   columns. 2020-01-29 16:45:17.507 13110-13169/xxx.debug E/SQLiteQuery:
>   exception: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0,
>   totalRows=10; query: SELECT * FROM CITIES WHERE CITY_NAME LIKE "stu%"
>   LIMIT 10 2020-01-29 16:45:17.508 13110-13169/xxx.debug W/Filter: An
>   exception occured during performFiltering()!
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=10
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:942)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:838)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:153)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:140)
>           at androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter.performFiltering(CursorFilter.java:54)
>           at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:236)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

The strange thing is that the result is very small and should not be affected by the window size linked in other answers where a real blob is stored in the database.
See a query result made with SQLite Manager Addon in Firefox:
[image: Example of successful query]

And this is how I create the cursor:

```
return readableDatabase.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM CITIES WHERE CITY_NAME LIKE \"$search%\" LIMIT 10",
        emptyArray()
    )
```